# Should I run reoccuring event every 15 minutes from within mysql, or through javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a site that hosts contests. Contests have a start and an end date-time. Contests can start in 15 minute intervals only (2:00, 2:15, 2:30...). I need to check the contests table every 15 minutes for records  in which the start time has passed, and change their status to "live". I need to check the contests every 15 minutes for records which end time have passed, and change their status to "complete".

My original thoughts were to create a mysql event to run every 15 minutes and handle this. However I have read that events are not very precise with timing, which is key here. Should I instead run this programatically using javascript?

Thoughts and advice would be wonderful.

Comment: Why do you only need to check every 15 minutes? Can you describe the ideal user experience

Comment: The contests start and end times have to be in 15 minute intervals, meaning they start at either hh:00, hh:15, hh:30, or hh:45. This means that I only need the event to check every 15 minutes for start/end times and change the contest status accordingly.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, why do you need to check at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to depend a lot on the environment/context that you are running in. You can always set up a serverless function that gets called every x amount of time and triggers the task. Otherwise, if you are running in a VPS a simple node script hooked up to a cron job will be more than sufficient.

Comment: I am using a VPS, I will try to run a cron job, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you are asking for but it would be the best way to do it in my opinion and will allow you to make a contest at any point in time even at an exact second

You can use [socket.io](https://socket.io/)

> Socket.IO enables real-time, bidirectional and event-based communication.
>   It works on every platform, browser or device, focusing equally on reliability and speed.

It will enable your app to run in real-time this
sounds like the ideal option for you it can be a bit of time to implement but is the easiest way to enable real-time in your app this also means users will not have to refresh the browser to see if a contest is active

Comment: Thank you I will look into adding this functionality in the future. On a bit of a time crunch now however.